# Crash and exit code 721035

Tags: aix, signals, core-dump

Where can I find what this exit code means?

I have process (A) that calls program (B) using clib system(). Sometimes program (B) returns with exit code 721035 and AIX kills process A. This is random and I would like to figure out what the exit code means and why it happens.

Here is a dbx stack trace:

```
[using memory image in core-prod]
reading symbolic information ...warning: Unable to access the stab file. Some info may not be available

Segmentation fault in pth_signal.pthread_kill [/usr/lib/libpthread.a] at 0xd05098c0 ($t1)
0xd05098c0 (pthread_kill+0xa0) 80410014         lwz   r2,0x14(r1)
(dbx) where
pth_signal.pthread_kill(??, ??) at 0xd05098c0
pth_signal._p_raise(??) at 0xd0508d28
raise.raise(??) at 0xd01373e0
skgesigOSCrash(??) at 0xd737cb7c
kpeDbgSignalHandler(??, ??) at 0xd73e2c54
skgesig_sigactionHandler(??, ??, ??) at 0xd737ce8c
get_from_list() at 0xd013cf04
malloc_buckets(??, ??) at 0xd01d9070
malloc_common@AF103_86(??) at 0xd012a448
pth_spinlock._lib_spinlock_create(??) at 0xd04f1344
_rec_mutex_init@AF20_14(??) at 0xd012b658
__bsd_child_post_fork() at 0xd0bdb230
pth_fork._atfork_child() at 0xd0515238
__fork() at 0xd0231378
system(??) at 0xd0303420
CSSCLIPal::System(const CSSCLIString&)(??) at 0xdbeb9880
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can also read [here](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21515029), this is probably a defect of the compiler you use. During the default optimization level it might generate incorrect code, making your application to fail and exit with 721035.

You can try to resolve this problem by selecting a lower optimization level during compilation. The default optimization level is -O2, so you can try compiling your code with -O1 or -O0.

The permanent solution (as stated in the link above) is to apply the the May 2011 PTF to your system.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that posting, along with the JVM one with the same exit code. Any idea if we can attach any meaning to the exit code? So far I could not find sysexits.h that gives a hint.

Comment: @DerickSchoonbee 721035 = 0xb008b. This looks like a value returned by [`waitpid` and friends](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.aix.basetechref/doc/basetrf2/wait_waitpid_wait3_wait364.htm), with a status of 0x8b. That status would be returned by a shell which detected that a program terminated with signal 0xb=11, which on many unices is SIGSEGV. If my interpretation is correct, I don't know what the 0xb0000 part indicates.